# get cell text in kendo grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I need to get the displayed text of a kendo grid, while iterating over the data. I have bee doing this:

```
    var data = grid.dataSource.data();
    var cols = grid.columns;

    for (var ri = 0; ri < data.length; ri++) {
        for (ci = 0; ci < cols.length; ci++) {
            var val = data[ri].get(cols[col].field);
            //do something with the cell data
            //but this gets me the model's value, not the displayed text
        }
    }
```

How can I get the displayed text in each cell?

Comment: Do you want to know what you have on each cell or what you have in each field? It is not the same since there are fields that might not be displayed and columns in grid might be hidden, rearranged,...

Comment: "displayed text" is what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, figured it out.

```
        var data = grid.dataSource.data();
        var cols = grid.columns;
        var field, template;

        for (var ri = 0; ri < data.length; ri++) {
            for (ci = 0; ci < cols.length; ci++) {
                field = cols[ci].field;
                template = cols[ci].template;
                if (field) {
                    var textval = data[ri][field];

                    if (template) {
                        var kt = kendo.template(template.toString());
                        textval = kt(data[ri]);
                        valType = 'string';
                    }

                    //do something with textval here
                }
            }
        }
```